# How to change the order of \chaptername and \thechapter in memoir chapter's head?

Tags: memoir, chapters, babel

I would like to create a Hungarian language `memoir` document.
The default `\chapterhead` command uses the order

```
 \printchaptername\chapternamenum\printchapternum
```

> (Chapter 1)

as it is explained at pp.84 of `memman.pdf`.

The Hungarian grammar requires the opposite order of chapter's name and chapter's number.
For example:

```
 \printchapternum. \chapternamenum\printchaptername.
```

> (1. Fejezet)

In the case of `book.cls` the problem is solved via the babel package `magyar.ldf` (v1.5).

How can I use that nice property of babel when the document class is memoir?

Comment: From the question i guess you have tried loading `babel`  along with `memoir`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example so we know whic chapterstyle you are using.

Comment: related: [How to write 1 Chapter instead of Chapter 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478756/116907) (book class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your own chapter style, you are responsible for the placement of the various elements. In order to change the standard chapter style, use a simple patch.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
 {\printchaptername \chapternamenum \printchapternum}
 {\printchapternum.\@\chapternamenum \printchaptername}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood well the problem is that `magyar.ldf` does not focus on `memoir` class at all. It would perhaps be nice to patch the `magyar.ldf` recognizing the case when the package `memoir` is loaded. @Johannes_B

Comment: @MGy `magyar.ldf` is essentially a collection of patches, with unreadable and undocumented code.

Comment: Would this work with sections, subsections, etc., and what would the commands be in this case?

Comment: @TheSodesa Sorry, I haven't the slightest idea. Working with `magyar.ldf` is a nightmare.

Comment: @TheSodesa I do not understand exactly your question. The problem was related to the chapter head. It is not usual to write Section 1, so there is no section, subsection, subsubsection head. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

If we prefer to use [lualatex](/questions/tagged/lualatex) compiler and use [polyglossia](/questions/tagged/polyglossia) instead of babel, then another minimalist solution is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hungarian}
%\usepackage[hungarian]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Tűz}
\end{document}
```

As the polyglossia manual writes: *''... polyglossia tries hard to provide the correct order for different classes and packages (standard classes, KOMA-script, memoir, and titlesec package should
work, as well as fancyhdr and caption).''* It is working since [polyglossia](/questions/tagged/polyglossia) v1.46. Very recently, thank you for Arthur Reutenauer at polyglossia, it is also working properly collaborating with the [hyperref](/questions/tagged/hyperref) package, since v1.53.