# How to write 1 Chapter instead of Chapter 1

Tags: sectioning, number

I want to write 1 Chapter instead of Chapter 1. Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: This depends on the documentclass you are using. Could you please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question?

Comment: You should take a look at the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Probably you're writing in a language different from English, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, then based on OP and comments under OP... This solution should suffice:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[basque]{babel} % <- choice based on OP's comment
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\chaptertitlename{kapitulua} % <- assuming that should be made lowercase when order changed
%\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}} % <- uncomment if you want Roman numerals instead
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\ \chaptertitlename}{20pt}{\Huge} % <- order changed (default is \chaptertitlename \ \thechapter)

\begin{document}

\chapter{Your title goes here}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from code]

Uncomment the line `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}` if you wish to use uppercase Roman numerals instead, i.e. "I chapter", "II chapter" instead of Arabic "1 chapter", "2 chapter".

Answer (score 1):

As @Bernard stated in his comment, you should use `titlesec` [package](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). The codes in pages 23 and 24 of the corresponding pdf file can be used. Read the descriptions on the pages for adjustments.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[rigidchapters,explicit]{titlesec}
\DeclareFixedFont{\chapterfont}{T1}{phv}{bx}{n}{4cm}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{100pt}{75pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\begin{picture}(0,230)}
{\put(450,80){%
\makebox(0,0)[rb]{%
{}}}
\put(0,270){%
\makebox(0,0)[lb]{%
\Huge\sffamily{\thechapter\ Chapter }}}}
{0pt}
{\put(0,200){\parbox[t]{300pt}{%
\Huge\sffamily\filright#1}}}
[\end{picture}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]